# Language : Java . App Eclipse. Java8.io.Find Demo not working

Tags: java, eclipse

Java8IODemo is not working. here is the code

```
public class FindDemo {

    public void showDemo() {
        System.out.println("=== Files.find() demo ===");
        try {
            Files.find(Paths.get("/"), 3, (path, attributes) -> {
                if (String.valueOf(path).equals("home")) {
                    System.out.println("FOUND : " + path);
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("\tNOT VALID : " + path);
                return false;
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: there's not even a main method, what did you expect would happen?

Comment: Call the method by `static void main(args[ ])` or transform it that way.

Comment: You should mention the error telling you it doesn't find the main method. This being the key and would have been easily solve with a few searches with any search engine.

Comment: Thank you, but i have a main method in main.java. here u can find this code:https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ilDPj4H8eQIjbRxmwQxiNYoQNTP_EEY

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a main-method. If you start a Java program without a main-method in a specified main-class (specified in `app.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`), nothing will happen. Adding it and calling the `showDemo()`-method

```
public class FindDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FindDemo().showDemo();
    }

    public void showDemo() {
        System.out.println("=== Files.find() demo ===");
        try {
            Files.find(Paths.get("/"), 3, (path, attributes) -> {
                if (String.valueOf(path).equals("home")) {
                    System.out.println("FOUND : " + path);
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("\tNOT VALID : " + path);
                return false;
            });
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

will produce with output:

```
=== Files.find() demo ===
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have a main method in main.java. here u can find this code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ilDPj4H8eQIjbRxmwQxiNYoQNTP_EEY

Comment: Alright, so that means the code is getting executed and you see at least "=== Files.find() demo ===", right? Now, where's the error?

Comment: I need to see smth like this in output                                                   
 : === BufferedReaderLines demo ===
package org.mik.lambda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {

 private String name;
 private String product;
 private int year;
 private float penetration;
 
 public Person() {}
 
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 } .......